# Is there a good version of Artin-Wedderburn for semisimple algebra objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Artin-Wederburn says that if you have a semisimple algebra then it is a product of matrix algebras over division rings.

Suppose that $C$ is a fusion category over the complex numbers (if you want to assume pivotal or similar things, that's fine, but don't assume symmetric or braided).  Suppose that $X$ is an algebra object in $C$.  That is $X$ is an object in $C$ together with a multiplication map $X \otimes X \rightarrow X$ and a unit etc.  We call $X$ semisimple if the category of $X$-module objects in $C$ is semisimple.  Is there some good analogue of Artin-Wedderburn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a paper on that topic:

- *Finite, connected, semisimple, rigid tensor categories are linear*, Math. Res. Lett. **10** (2003), 411-421, doi:[10.4310/MRL.2003.v10.n4.a1](https://doi.org/10.4310/MRL.2003.v10.n4.a1), arXiv:[math/0209256](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209256).

Comment: Hrm, I think I need to spend some more serious time with that paper.  I think this is not the first time (and maybe not the second either) that I've asked a question and you've said the answer was in this paper.  I even read it after one of those times.

Comment: Ok, so certainly this is some form of Artin-Wedderburn, but I don't think it's of the form I was looking for.  Your result says that just as semisimple rings are always algebras over a field fusion rings are also always linear over some field.  But what I wanted wasn't something that replaced semisimple rings with fusion categories but rather something that replaced semisimple rings in Vect with semisimple rings in some other category.